# Need help to exclude posts from wordpress blog home page

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to exclude posts from my index page. I have the below code in my functions.php to accomplish that:

```
function my_cat_exclude($query) {
 if ($query->is_home) {
  //$query->set('cat','-1,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10');
  $query->set('cat','11');
 }
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','my_cat_exclude');
```

I have 12 categories in my blog. I would like to show posts from only one category (category id 11). I don't want to show the rest on homepage.

If I use `$query->set('cat','-1,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10');` it doesn't show posts which shares the same category with category id 11. For example, if a post is assigned to two categories category id 5 and category 11, then, it doesn't shows that post in my home page. I would like to show all posts belong to category id 11 on my home page.

If I use `$query->set('cat','11');` It shows only category with category id 11. however, it removes the other category posts, custom menus from sidebar widget. Also, removes the menu items from top menu.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your code and this works fine on my dev site.

```
function my_cat_exclude() {
    if ( is_home() ) {
        query_posts( 'cat=11' );
    }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','my_cat_exclude');
```

Comment: add_filter is in plugin.php so you have to add at the top of functions.php


`require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/plugin.php' );`